# How can I convert 13 character length string to datetime format in ruby-on-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I imported some sms messages in an xml file; there's a "date" field where the date is expressed as 13 digits but it's a string I imported them into a string column but I don't know how to display, query or manipulate the dates

Example of such string

```rb
msg['date']
# => "1616508915508"
```

Comment: 3.1.2 :026 > Time.at(msg['date'].to_i).to_datetime
 => Thu, 16 Feb 53195 17:18:28 -0500 I don't know what 53195 means, is that a year?

Comment: 3.1.2 :028 > msg['date']
 => "1616508915508"

Answer (score 0):

It looks main problem is that your string in millisecond Unix time format

You can convert it to seconds and after that manipulate as you want

```rb
msg["date"] = "1616508915508"
seconds = msg["date"].to_f / 1000 # => 1616508915.508
```

Convert to time

```rb
time = Time.at(seconds, in: "UTC") # => 2021-03-23 14:15:15 1065353/2097152 UTC
```

(you can omit `:in` option to get time in current time zone, or specify other zone)

Convert to datetims

```rb
time.to_datetime # => Tue, 23 Mar 2021 14:15:15 +0000
```

Comment: If I don't use to_f I can't get a decimal result from the division by 1000 ?

Comment: In mahy records the 13 digit string is in a mysql datetime field Next time I use the sms backup and restore app I'm gonna get another xml file with the 13 digits in plain text What do you recommend? How should I manipulate them before importing them to the database? Maybe I should move them to another column with a different data type

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake I don't think there are any records in 13 digit format already in the datetime column in the database they're in a string column Not important

Comment: Using to_f returns the same time as without using it except with additional digits separated by a forward slash  "=> 2021-03-23 10:15:15 1065353/2097152 -0400" Even if I don't use it what is the -0400 part?

Comment: If I name my model Sms then there's no plural Is that a problem?